# Passing dependencies from module to inherited parent module

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, dagger-2, okhttp

I have a base abstract module that provides some dependencies for Retrofit/OkHttp related objects. This module is missing some dependencies, and I've created another module that extends this module to provide these missing dependencies.

Here's what the base abstract module looks like:

```
@Module
abstract class BaseApiModule {

    @[Provides Singleton]
    fun provideOkHttpClient(interceptors: List<Interceptor>) : OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .apply {
                for (interceptor in interceptors) {
                    addInterceptor(interceptor)
                }
            }
            .build()
    }

    @[Provides Singleton]
    fun provideRetrofit(
        baseUrl: String,
        okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
    }
}
```

Here's what the module that implements this abstract module looks like:

```
@Module
object ApiModule : BaseApiModule() {

    @[JvmStatic Provides Singleton]
    fun provideBaseUrl() = "https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/"

    @[JvmStatic Provides Singleton]
    fun provideInterceptors() = listOf<Interceptor>(HttpLoggingInterceptor())

    @[JvmStatic Provides Singleton]
    fun provideApi(retrofit: Retrofit) = retrofit.create(Api::class.java)
}
```

I'm trying to establish the modules in a way where:
 - BaseApiModule is missing some dependencies
 - ApiModule provides these dependencies

This implementation isn't working for me: whenever I build my code, I get the following error: `error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] @com.example.api.Interceptors java.util.List<? extends okhttp3.Interceptor> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method`. If I remove the interceptors dependencies completely, my code builds just fine. I'd like an explanation on:

- Why does this module setup break and why does it build when I remove the dependencies on a `List<Interceptor>`
- What's the standard way in dagger to have a module supply missing dependencies to another module?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by making `ApiModule` not a singleton object and removing all JvmStatic annotations from it.